# DataTable row selection inside shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to take this basic working shiny app and modularize it. This works:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("testTable"),
    verbatimTextOutput("two")
  ),
  server = function(input,output) {
    output$testTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    }, selection=list(mode="multiple",target="row"))

    output$two <- renderPrint(input$testTable_rows_selected) 
  }
)
```

I want to make this a module that will work for any data.frame

```
# UI element of module for displaying datatable
testUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DT::dataTableOutput(ns("testTable"))

}
# server element of module that takes a dataframe
# creates all the server elements and returns
# the rows selected
test <- function(input,output,session,data) {
  ns <- session$ns
  output$testTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data()
  }, selection=list(mode="multiple",target="row"))

  return(input[[ns("testTable_rows_selected")]])

}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    testUI("one"),
    verbatimTextOutput("two")
  ),
  server = function(input,output) {
    out <- callModule(test,"one",reactive(mtcars))
    output$two <- renderPrint(out()) 
  }
)
```

This gives me errors saying I am trying to use reactivity outside of a reactive environment. If I eliminate the return statement, it runs. Is there anyway to return the rows selected from a datatable in a shiny module?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Needed

```
return(reactive(input$testTable_rows_selected))
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question with your own given answer is still quite relevant, I want to give an update of the code in regards of using `shiny` modules:

```
testUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    DT::dataTableOutput(NS(id, "mytable")),
    verbatimTextOutput(NS(id, "selected"))
  )
}

testServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    }, selection = list(mode = "multiple", target = "row"))
    
    output$selected <- renderPrint(
      input$mytable_rows_selected  # Caution: The prefix must match the id of my namespace
    )
    
  })
}


testApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    testUI("test")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    testServer("test")
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

testApp()
```